# Is it possible to get region (location) for call in the calls history?

Tags: android, phone-call

How to get location of call? Not full location, just a region? Maybe android has some API for that? Didn't found with content resolver and CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its based on area code.  And sometimes exchange (the first 3 digits of the number calling you after the area code).  You can find tables for the data, for example area code is here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_American_Numbering_Plan_area_codes

Please note that these locations are not the actual location someone was at.  With the ability to take your number with you between plans and mobile phones being a thing, these are far from accurate to where the call actually originated.  If I called you you'd see Seattle WA, but I haven't lived there in a decade.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)